# Derivative of x^2 * sin(x)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Wrong question**

Sorry guys, I've mixed sign and sgn functions. ;(

---

First of all sorry, I could't get mathjax working properly, so I had to use ASCII only for this time, I apologize about that.

**The question**

How should the function x^2 * sin(x) be defined at x = 0 so that it is continuous there? Is it then differentiable there?

**Solution**

```
x^2 * sin(x) = x|x| = {  
    x^2 if x > 0
    -x^2 if x < 0
}
```

Will become continuous and differentiable at x = 0 if we
define g(0) = 0.

**My question**

We know that its continuous and differentiable since we check the limit of `x|x|` from the right and left side...

But how did we end up with: `x^2 * sin(x) = x|x|`?

**Book images**

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmJa9.png)

[Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYspR.png)

Comment: I don't understand your problem, because $x^2\sin x$ has no issues at all: it is perfectly computable at $0$ by substitution: it's $0^2\sin 0=0\cdot 0=0$. And, needless to say, it is $C^\infty$. All its derivatives can be computed with elementary properties such as $\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=n x^{n-1},\ \frac{d}{dx}(\sin x)=\cos x,\ \frac{d}{dx}(\cos x)=-\sin x$

Comment: $x^2\sin x \neq x|x|$

Comment: Is that the solution you found in the book/exercise?

Comment: @user160738 Yes I was surprised by it, I couldn't make sens of it, I don't know why does the book make them equal.

Comment: @dud3 can you upload a photo of the solution? Maybe you are misinterpreting it

Comment: @Euler_Salter yes.

Comment: @Euler_Salter On my way, just a sec.

Comment: @Euler_Salter question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmJa9.png answer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYspR.png

Comment: @dud3 it's the function sign!!

Comment: @dud3 the function sign gives you, as its name says, the sign of the argument!

Comment: @Euler_Salter OMG, just hit my head on the table, wow, I'm so used to sign, what's does sgn mean?

Comment: Oh how lovely, I've totally confused myself with sign, well at lest the book should have been warning me. ;( Totally wasted 30min on trying to make sense out of it.

Thanks. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the function $sng(x)$ to much, however I guess some kind of explanation is the following $x^2sgn(x)$ is positive if $sgn(x)$ is $sgn(x) = +$, while it is negative if $sgn(x) = -$ as $x^2\geq 0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Notice that the magnitude of $x^2sgn(x)$ is simply the magnitude of $x^2$ as the $sgn(x)$ function only adds an extra sign.

So basically if $x>0$ then $sgn(x)>0$, i.e. $sgn(x) = +1$, so we have $x^2sgn(x) = +x^2 = |x^2| =x|x| $ as for $x>0$ we have $x = |x|$.

If $x<0$, then $|x| = -x$ and $sgn(x) = -1$, hence $x^2sgn(x) = -x^2 = - |x^2| = -|x||x| = -(-x)|x| = x|x|$.

Finally if $x = 0$ you clearly have that the function outputs $0$.